# Iterate addition if condition is true

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I need to figure out how translate a nucleic acid sequence and count the number of protein motifs in the translated sequence. I have some code to translate the sequence and search for walker motifs. It'll identify which sequences have walker motifs, but won't iterate a count to determine how many sequences have the motif. I'm not exactly sure what's wrong to get my if statement to iterate. I'm very grateful for any guidance

```
for index, sequence in enumerate(all_sequences):#so for all of your sequences in the all_sequence file
    translation = translate(sequence) #run the translate program
    found=bool(re.search(motif, translation))#now search for your motif after every translation        
    total_walker=0 #initialize at 0
    if found == True: #so if you find it
            print('This sequence has a walker motif :)')#shows you who has a walker motif
            **total_walker=total_walker+1#I want this to add 1 every time a walker shows up but it isn't iterable and I honestly have no clue why :(**
    print(total_walker)
    print(f"Sequence: {index + 1}")#I couldn't figure out how to put the cDNA fasta tag back in on time :( So I labelled them by numbers
    #It's not great but this will let the user go back to the input file and figure out which is which. But it isn't automated and that's all very sad
    print(translation)
    print()#and now all of your lovely sequences will come back
```

Comment: Why would you set total_walker  to 0 every time it loop?

Comment: total_walker is not iterable because it's an *int*

Comment: UMR you're a god to me